# jQuery autocomplete @mention

Tags: joomla-3.x, jquery

I have a json encoded string which contains a couple of users:

```
$users = json_encode($helper->getAllUsers());
```

a textarea:

```
<textarea id="jj_message"></textarea>
```

and am using the jQuery autocomplete plugin that comes shipped with Joomla:

```
JHtml::_('script', 'media/jui/js/jquery.autocomplete.min.js');

$script = "
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var users = " . $users . ";

        $('#jj_message').autocomplete({
            lookup: users,
            lookupLimit: 5,
            delimiter: ' '
        });
    });
";

$doc->addScriptDeclaration($script);
```

Now in my textarea, if I start typing in a name, for example `Lod`, then the jQuery autocomplete will provide `Lodder` as the result.

However, what I'd like to do is initiate the autocomplete when a user types in a name with the `@` symnbol at the beginning, for example, `@Lod`.

Currently when I do this, no results are displayed.

Have anyone ever achieved this with Joomla's built in autocomplete plugin?

Comment: Maybe this helps you a little bit: https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete

Comment: I would probably try something with onSearchStart, because this is called before the AJAX request. Maybe there is a way to transform the search query from @Lod to Lod before it fires.

Comment: I'm probably over simplifying things, but couldn't you just add @ to each of the usernames before using json_encode? http://stackoverflow.com/a/28115783/691053

Comment: I ended up using a different jQuery plugin (mention.js and typeahead.js). I've post the full answer later on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will just post this as a reference.

I ended up using a jQuery plugin called [Mention.js](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Mention.js) which utilises a standalone version of Bootstrap's Typeahead plugin.

The code I then wrote which is just a Beta concept is:

```
$users = json_encode($helper->getAllUsers());

JHtml::_('script', 'mod_mymodule/mention.min.js', false, true);
JHtml::_('script', 'mod_mymodule/typeahead.min.js', false, true);

$doc->addScriptDeclaration("
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var users = " . $users . ";

        $('#element').mention({
            delimiter: '@',
            users: users,
            typeaheadOpts: {
                menu: '<ul class=\"myclass typeahead\"></ul>'
            }
        });

    });
");
```